# Mysql query for DB_ROW_ID value

Tags: mysql

Here im trying to retrive a value for DB_ROW_ID which is a internal field added by InnoDb engine while creating a no Primary key table.
The basic purpose is to get the internal column id to map it with table in later part of query.

Is there is any way to query for the those internal coloumns or how can i store a row id without creating primary key on table

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No you can't get that. If you want, you need to create your own auto-increment primary key. Full answer:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40644/is-it-possible-to-select-internal-innodb-columns